# 3D Pie Drilldown chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, highcharts

I need to make `3D` `Pie` Chart with `Drilldown` effect.I can not figure it out how it work.

3D Pie Chart [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/oet0r22k/2/)

2D Pie Chart with Drilldown  [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/d9wxgp5u/2/)

And here is my attempt [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/n2og0rc7/4/)

CODE:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
                type: 'pie',
            options3d: {
              enabled: true,
              alpha: 45,
              beta: 0
            }
          },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the slices to view versions. Source: netmarketshare.com.'
        },
                plotOptions: {
            pie: {
              allowPointSelect: true,
              cursor: 'pointer',
              depth: 35,
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%',
                style: {
                  color: 'black'
                }
              }
          }
      },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                y: 56.33,
                drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 24.03,
                drilldown: 'Chrome'
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                y: 10.38,
                drilldown: 'Firefox'
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                y: 4.77,
                drilldown: 'Safari'
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                y: 0.91,
                drilldown: 'Opera'
            }, {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                y: 0.2,
                drilldown: null
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                data: [
                    ['v11.0', 24.13],
                    ['v8.0', 17.2],
                    ['v9.0', 8.11],
                    ['v10.0', 5.33],
                    ['v6.0', 1.06],
                    ['v7.0', 0.5]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                id: 'Chrome',
                data: [
                    ['v40.0', 5],
                    ['v41.0', 4.32],
                    ['v42.0', 3.68],
                    ['v39.0', 2.96],
                    ['v36.0', 2.53],
                    ['v43.0', 1.45],
                    ['v31.0', 1.24],
                    ['v35.0', 0.85],
                    ['v38.0', 0.6],
                    ['v32.0', 0.55],
                    ['v37.0', 0.38],
                    ['v33.0', 0.19],
                    ['v34.0', 0.14],
                    ['v30.0', 0.14]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                id: 'Firefox',
                data: [
                    ['v35', 2.76],
                    ['v36', 2.32],
                    ['v37', 2.31],
                    ['v34', 1.27],
                    ['v38', 1.02],
                    ['v31', 0.33],
                    ['v33', 0.22],
                    ['v32', 0.15]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                id: 'Safari',
                data: [
                    ['v8.0', 2.56],
                    ['v7.1', 0.77],
                    ['v5.1', 0.42],
                    ['v5.0', 0.3],
                    ['v6.1', 0.29],
                    ['v7.0', 0.26],
                    ['v6.2', 0.17]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                id: 'Opera',
                data: [
                    ['v12.x', 0.34],
                    ['v28', 0.24],
                    ['v27', 0.17],
                    ['v29', 0.16]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is drilldown.js. Just include it and it will work

[See the working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/n2og0rc7/8/)

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nishith Kant Chaturvedi. Actually I forgot to see script section.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely perfect. There are no issues with it. You have just forgotten to include the javascript file for drilldown.

Just include the script file and your work will be done.

Comment: Thanks @Yash Vora. Actually I forgot to see script section